# Hyperledger Fabric Asset vs Transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, chaincode

What is the difference between add/update assets directly vs add/update assets through transaction. Which is the right way to do?

We can add/update assets using API then why we perform transaction on assets? Is this like a log/trace to track what and when things updated on assets? What If I made changes in assets directly without any transaction entries? or should I do changes through transactions on assets?

For Example:

```
asset Myasset identified by asset_id {
  o String asset_id      
  --> User admin    
  o String firstname
  o String lastname
  o Boolean status default=true
}


transaction UpdateMyasset {
    o Myasset certificate
    o Boolean status default=true
}
```

So should I use UpdateMyasset to create assets or directly use Myasset? When should I use transaction?

Comment: Sry i don't get the question. It is not Transaction vs Assets, it is creating/updating assets through transactions. Maybe read here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/fabric_model.html to understand the meaning behind those terms in hyperledger fabric context.

Comment: Yes, its creating/updating assets through, So what you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

this is actually a very good question.

you are correct, there are two ways to create / update assets and that part has never sit right with me. The API, by default, gives you endpoints to create / update assets.

In my mind that is a problem, because it's bypassing any kind of business rules you might have. These rules can be specified and applied however via a transaction. At that point you can check your asset, make sure everything is good and if all business rules are fulfilled, then you can create / update your asset.

What I think should be done in a serious, non POC kind of application, is to completely disable the asset endpoints and only create / update assets via transactions and only once the business rules have been applied and your assets properly validated.

Comment: Sry i still don't understand the question. Can you maybe provide sth to read so i get the problem/solution? Is this something composer specific?